# How can I copy large number of files from one Ubuntu machine to another effectively?

Tags: ubuntu

I have two Ubuntu machines, one of which has a large number of files.

How can I copy the files from one machine to another effectively? I would like to copy only the delta files and not all the files every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try using [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)

**Guides:**

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html

http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/

> It can perform differential uploads and downloads (synchronization) of files across the network, transferring only data that has changed. The rsync remote-update protocol allows rsync to transfer just the differences between two sets of files across the network connection.

Comment: small tip, replacing `-e ssh` with `-e "ssh -C"` turns on SSH data compression, which will give you a bit of speed boost.