# How to properly migrate a constantly changing set of files from one NAS to another?

Tags: backup, rsync, migration

I am [moving 4.4TB of files from one NAS to another, both running Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/335916/how-can-i-copy-large-number-of-files-from-one-ubuntu-machine-to-another-effectiv). However there is one thing that made me a bit worried whether rsync would work or not: there is a folder whose contents that is constantly changing.

This constantly-changing folder is the Time Capsule backup of my Mac - 2.4TB worth of backed-up backlog of potentially deleted files, in one OS X "Sparse Bundle" (which is effectively a growing disk image consists of a whole bunch of small files, like those virtual machine hard disk images, but kept in a format that OS X considers as a single file or object).

Can rsync migrate this? Do I need to turn my Mac off during migration?

Comment: When backing up any "mission critical" data you should make sure nothing is using it at the time - purely for this reason. If a file is copied and being used at the same time then there is always a chance for corruption to occur.

Comment: @BigChris So your suggestion is turn my Mac off during the migration?

Comment: To minimise the potential for corruption, yes.

Comment: @BigChris If I have to turn off my Mac during migrating of this "sparse bundle", can I make this downtime shorter by migrating this bundle and only this bundle first, then migrate the rest of the data with my Mac on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are LVM style options for you to mount one of the NAS servers on the other and have it Mirror the file system.  the biggest problem with this approach is it will be much slower.  and you still need to take a small outage when you switch to the final destination.

My recommendation would be to do a run of Rsync with everything online then do a second run copying the updates only after stopping all writes.  This gives you time to go update all those pesky configs pointing to the old NAS.

Comment: So to round up, I just rsync with my Mac on, wait until it finishes, turn my Mac off, then rsync again?

Comment: Got this solution work after running into & sorting out a few connection issues. Thanks